# Зачем нужны библиотеки типа React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я так понял, что они нужны для динамического обновления данных в доме, но для этого нужен массив с данными, а получать их с помощью `Ajax` довольно проблематично. На мой взгляд проще сделать вывод через `php`, где можно сразу обратиться к бд. Если это так, тогда зачем?

Comment: Разделение приложения на клиент и сервер - имеет много плюсов.

Comment: Советую подробнее познакомиться с концепцией Single-Page Application и рендерингом на стороне пользователя. Такие фреймворки нужны именно для этого. Предполагается, что солидная часть вычислительной нагрузки, касающаяся взаимодействия с пользователем, ложится на его браузер. В то время как серверу остаётся работать с данными.

Answer (score 2):

При выводе через php у вас на сервере будет генерироваться вся разметка, и если пользователь захочет получить еще данные, то ему придется обновить всю страницу. Если пользователь выполнит какое-то действие на странице, то ему опять придется обновить всю страницу. Библиотеки типа React позволяют создавать динамичные и интерактивные пользовательские интерфейсы, опять же получать данные с ajax совсем не проблематично, такие библиотеки и фреймворки заточены на это. В данном случае вы отделяете Frontend и Backend на независимые единицы которые могут общаться по api. Так что ответ такой - с библиотеками типа React намного проще разрабатывать и поддерживать пользовательские интерфейсы, где не нужно делать обновление всей страницы на каждый чих. И второе, на сервере вы работаете только с данными и не генерируете разметку, что положительно сказывается на производительности сервера.